# Prestashop 1.6.1.15 back office login problem

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a problem with login to the back office of my prestashop.

No matter if I put correct or wrong password, the login form is redirecting me to the page from the screenshot below.

[image]

However, the Google Chrome Console doesnt show any errors.

I have no idea where to look for the solution so i thought that maybe you guys have any suggestions.

@update1: I've tried to change admin login directory but it doesn't work.

Comment: Since today i have the same problem with 1.6.1.17

Comment: Try turning on the debug mode from `defines.inc.php` and try in a private tab of your browser to discard cookies or browser cache.

Comment: It seems there is only a login problem in the backend with javascript / ajax. When is disable js i can login. After i'm logged in i can enable js and it works fine.

Comment: Try turning on debug mode and then check network tab instead console to see response of requests.

Comment: The debug mode is on. There is the a request on ajax-tab.php and this calls the https://www.example.com/adminasdfadf/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=f22ff8e483020d1de068ee1e3589e906&email=info@example.com

and the response is html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now. With no changes in the code: It works again live and on my local machine. So i guess there was something wrong with things that was loaded behind the scene from prestashop servers.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can have many reasons.

My guess is that you changed "**PS_COOKIE_LIFETIME_BO**" value.

check it on ps_configuration table on your database. default value is 480

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've checked in the database and it was already set to 480.

Comment: Well then you can try to disable check IP from configuration table.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. In the *controllers/admin/AdminLoginController.php* file, I removed line 54. Specifically, add JS - **$this->addJS(PS_JS_DIR.'vendor/ladda.js');**

Now without ladda.js I log in correctly.